# Openstack instance storage repo

Tags: instance, openstack, qemu

I have some **openstack** instances and I want to know on which part of my disk these instances are stored; Can anyone help me to know that?

Answer (score 1):

Usually `/var/lib/nova/instances`, or the value of [instances_path](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/configuration/config.html#DEFAULT.instances_path).

Should you use KVM as hypervisor, you can also find this out by reading the virtual machine's XML file: List the VMs `virsh list`, then `virsh dumpxml VM`, where VM is the number or the name of a VM. Or by listing the VM's block devices `virsh domblklist VM`.